# Is socket.id unique over time, should it be kept private?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am writing a game for a (size limited) gamejam.

I want to create a leaderboard and the easiest way to store the entries would be based on the player's socket.id.

Am I safe to do so, or is there a chance that it will be given again to a player in the future?

Also, should I keep it as a secret or am I safe to send it out to the clients as part of the leaderboard? (i.e. can a random player use this ID to interfere with the legitimate player with the ID from the leaderboard?)

Comment: From the [documentation](//socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html#socket-id): _“[A] unique identifier for the socket session. Set after the `connect` event is triggered, and updated after the `reconnect` event.”_.

Comment: Thanks, but how unique is it? For the lifetime of the server? Locally to the machine (i.e. derived from process id, etc.)? Universally?

Comment: Related: [How unique is socket.id?](/q/20962970/4642212).

Comment: @GaborHeja lifetime of the socket session, per client, usually. Can't remember if Socket.io has a 'sticky' option to retain the ID across sessions, but unless you are using some form of persistent store then it's a fairly unreliable option for your use-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `socket.id` lasts only for the duration of a given socket.io session.  A future socket.io connection from the same client will be given a new `socket.id`.  As such, it is NOT a lasting identifier and thus I wouldn't think it would be very useful for a leaderboard because it would not necessarily attribute multiple scores from the same user (in different sessions) to be the same user.  Instead, you would want a lasting user identifier that your own server creates (usually as part of a user signup/signin process) and can long term make sure it's both unique and that the same client gets the same identifier each time.

As to how unique a `socket.id` is, it is coined via random number generation.  It uses the module base64id to create the unique id and the [doc for that module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64id) says that it uses `crypto.randomBytes()`.  You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/faeldt/base64id/blob/master/lib/base64id.js#L80).

So, with random number generation, **it is probabilistically unique, not guaranteed unique.**   At first look at the base64id module, it appears that it appends an increasing number to the random bytes under some circumstances which could make it guaranteed unique during a server lifetime (without server restarts) assuming no roll-over of the increasing digits, but still won't keep the same id for the same client across different sessions.

> should it be kept private

**A `socket.id` is created/assigned at the server, thus there is no ability for a client to try to spoof or use some other user's socket.id.  As such, there's no particular reason to keep it private.**  It's just a unique id that socket.io uses for internal bookkeeping to keep track of state for a given connection.

If you've ever looked at a socket.id, it is not particularly meant for human consumption and/or displaying in a UI.  It's a string of base64 that will look largely like gibberish to most regular users if displayed in a leaderboard.  More commonly, a user would specify their own "display name" when they signed up for your service and you'd use that in a leaderboard and you'd use that as the persistent identifier from one session to the next.